# Weird result when grouping and self-joining a table

Tags: mysql

I'm on MySQL 5.5.49, the results of the following query seem wrong to me.

Test data :

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `invoice_item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `previous_invoice_item_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(12,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO test (invoice_id, previous_invoice_item_id, price)
VALUES (1, NULL, 1), (1, 1, 0);
```

Query :

```
SELECT
 ii.invoice_item_id,
 pii.invoice_item_id,
 ii.previous_invoice_item_id,
 ii.price - pii.price,
 ii.price,
 pii.price
FROM test ii
JOIN test pii ON pii.invoice_item_id = ii.previous_invoice_item_id
GROUP BY ii.invoice_item_id;
```

The problem is that `ii.price - pii.price` returns `0` when it should return `-1`. If I remove the `GROUP BY` clause, the result is correct. If the difference is positive, the result is also correct.

I'm at a loss to explain the result, can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Which exact version of MySQL do you use? Seems like a bug - although I can't understand what's the point of the `GROUP BY` there. `ii.invoice_itme_id` is the primary key of the table.

Comment: `5.5.49-0+deb7u1-log (Debian)` to be more precise. The `GROUP BY` is there because the original query is much more complicated and needs it.

Comment: Well, if there is a more complicated query, add it in the question. It would be interesting. `GROUP BY` the primary key is not useful, at least not in this query. Still you got an answer. Seems like the combination of `signed` integers and `GROUP BY` confuses MySQL. I'll check later if there is any similar bug reported.

Comment: Version 8.0 complains:  `ERROR 1690 (22003): DECIMAL UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`ii`.`price` - `pii`.`price`)'` with or without the `GROUP BY`.  So, if you write a bug report; they will probably say 'fixed'.

Comment: See the 'variable' `sql_mode`, in particular `NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION`.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks a lot for your explanations that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your `price` column is `unsigned`.

[CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)ing the values works ok:

```
SELECT
 ii.invoice_item_id,
 pii.invoice_item_id,
 ii.previous_invoice_item_id,
 cast(ii.price as signed) - cast(pii.price as signed ),
 ii.price,
 pii.price
FROM test ii
JOIN test pii ON pii.invoice_item_id = ii.previous_invoice_item_id
GROUP BY ii.invoice_item_id
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, but the thing I don't understand is why the result is signed if grouping and unsigned if not?